# New Relic python agent + gunicorn + gevent crashing

Tags: python, django, heroku, newrelic, gevent

I am switching my application over to use gevent instead of threads with gunicorn. I have also been using New Relic to monitor my application successfully.

However, when I using the combination of both of them, my application becomes really laggy ans also crashes. In the moment, I remove gevent or New Relic, everyhing works fine. This would be my goal to work:

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn config.wsgi_gevent:application -c config/gunicorn_gevent.config.py --worker-class gevent --worker-connections 100 --max-requests=100 --max-requests-jitter=50  --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

As said, that one does not work. These ones do:

1. New relic  + threads

   `web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000`
2. Gunicorn with gevent

   `web: gunicorn config.wsgi_gevent:application -c config/gunicorn_gevent.config.py --worker-class gevent --worker-connections 100 --max-requests=100 --max-requests-jitter=50 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000`

Logs before the browser is just loading and nothing happens anymore:

```
    12:05:53 AM web.1 |  [2023-04-19 00:05:53 +0300] [14496] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
12:05:53 AM web.1 |  [2023-04-19 00:05:53 +0300] [14496] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (14496)
12:05:53 AM web.1 |  [2023-04-19 00:05:53 +0300] [14496] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
12:05:53 AM web.1 |  [2023-04-19 00:05:53 +0300] [14499] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14499
12:06:07 AM web.1 |  [2023-04-18 21:06:07 +0000] [14499] [INFO] Autorestarting worker after current request.
12:06:08 AM web.1 |  [2023-04-18 21:06:08 +0000] [14499] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14499)
12:06:08 AM web.1 |  Monkey patching all the things!
12:06:08 AM web.1 |  Already patched
12:06:38 AM web.1 |  [2023-04-19 00:06:38 +0300] [14496] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14499)
12:06:51 AM web.1 |  [2023-04-19 00:06:51 +0300] [14256] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
12:06:51 AM web.1 |  Monkey patching all the things!
12:06:51 AM web.1 |  Already patched
12:06:51 AM web.1 Exited Successfully
```

gunicorn_config.gevent.py

```
from gevent import monkey


print("Monkey patching all the things!")
try:
    monkey.patch_all()
except ReferenceError:
    print("Already patched")
```

wsgi_gevent.py

```
import gevent.monkey  # isort:skip  noqa

gevent.monkey.patch_all()  # isort:skip  noqa

import os  # noqa
import sys  # noqa

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application  # noqa


app_path = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), os.pardir)
)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(app_path, "app_name"))

# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "config.settings.production"
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.production")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: How does it crash? What's in the logs?